# Edit an item by clicking on the Catalog number

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I'm having a bit of a hard time trying to figure out how to have a modal pop up with populated information about the item selected via catalog number.  The catalog number has the trigger to open up the modal.  I'm pretty new to ajax and modals so any help would be appreciated! :)

Loading the table:

```
function loadCollectionIndex() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/getAllCollectables/all',
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(items) {
        var tbody = $('tbody');

        for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i];
            var colorString = '';
            var keywordString = '';

            item.colors.forEach(function(value, index, color) {
                if (index == (color.length - 1)) {
                    colorString += value.name;
                } else {
                    colorString += value.name + ', ';
                }
            });

            item.keywords.forEach(function(value, index, keyword) {
                if (index == (keyword.length - 1)) {
                    keywordString += value.keywordName;
                } else {
                    keywordString += value.keywordName + ', ';
                }
            });

            tbody.append('<tr id="itemCatalogNumberRow" class="newRow"><td class="itemCatalogNumber" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateModal">'
                    + item.itemCatalogNumber 
                    + '</td><td class="itemName">'
                    + item.itemName
                    + '</td><td class="itemCategory">'
                    + item.category.categoryType
                    + '</td><td class="itemDescription">'
                    + item.itemDescription
                    + '</td><td class="itemAge">'
                    + item.itemAge
                    + '</td><td class="itemCondition">'
                    + item.condition.conditionName
                    + '</td><td class="itemColor">'
                    + colorString
                    + '</td><td class="itemKeyword">'
                    + keywordString
                    + '</td><td class="itemSold">'
                    + item.sold
                    + '</td></tr>');
        }
    });
```

This is the ajax I have so far for the update box:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/getAllCollectables/all',
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(collectables){
        var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(collectables));
        var item;
        for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
        {
            item = obj[i];
            $("#updateCollectableSelect").append('<option value='+item.collectableId+'>' + item.itemName + '</option>');
        }
    });

    // On select change
    $("#updateCollectableSelect").on("change", function() {
        onUpdateSelect();
    });

    // On submit click
    $("#updateSubmit").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        updateItem();
    });
```

Here's the HTML for the update modal:

```
<div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="updateModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

         <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"> Add an Item </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="updateItem">
                        <form>
                            <select name = "dropDownMenu" id="updateCollectableSelect">
                                <option value = "Select a Collectable"> Select a Collectable </option>
                            </select>
                            <div>
                                <label> ID Number </label><br>
                                    <span id="updateIdNum"></span>
                            <br></div>
                            <br><div>
                                <label> Catalog Number </label>
                                <input type="text" id="updateItemCatalogNumber"> 
                                <p class="error" id="updateItemCatalogNumberError"></p> 
                            <br></div>
                            <br><div>
                                <label> Collectable Name </label>
                                <input type="text" id="updateItemName"> 
                                <p class="error" id="updateItemNameError"></p>
                            <br></div>
                            <br><div>
                                <label> Collectable Age </label>
                                <input type="text" id="updateItemAge">
                                <p class="error" id="updateItemAgeError"></p>

                            <br></div>
                            <br><div>
                                <label> Collectable Description </label>
                                <input type="text"  id="updateItemDescription">
                                <p class="error" id="updateItemDescriptionError"></p>
                            <br></div>
                            <br><div id="categorySelectDiv">
                                <select id="addCatagorySelect" class="" name="catagorySelect">
                                    <option class="" value="select">Select Category</option>
                                </select>
                            <br></div>
                            <br><div id="conditionSelectDiv">
                                <select id="addConditionSelect" class="" name="conditionSelect">
                                    <option class="" value="select">Select Condition</option>
                                </select>
                            <br></div>
                            <br><div id="addColorDiv">
                                <div id="colorSelectDiv">
                                    <select id="addColorSelect" class="" name="colorSelect" multiple>
                                        <option class="" value="select">Select Color</option>
                                    </select>
                                <br></div>
                                <div>
                                    <p>Hold down the Ctrl button to select multiple color options.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div id="addKeywordDiv">
                                    <div id="keywordSelectDiv">
                                        <select id="addKeywordSelect" class="" name="keywordSelect" multiple>
                                            <option class="" value="select">Select Keyword</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>Hold down the Ctrl button to select multiple keyword options.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>      
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Submit </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Can you update your question with the response of `getAllCollectables/all`? Open Google Chrome Developer Tools in the Network tab.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i've simulated approximately your scenario that you have with ajax request to finally to show you a possible solution, to solve your question.

The json data from my test server (http://dfjb.webcindario.com/getAllCollectables.php?action=all) is:

```
[
    {
        "collectableId": 1,
        "itemCatalogNumber": 150,
        "itemName": "name...",
        "category": {
            "categoryType": "category Type..."
        },
        "itemDescription": "item desc...",
        "itemAge": 29,
        "condition": {
            "conditionName": "condition Name..."
        },
        "sold": 10,
        "colors": [
            {
                "name": "Red"
            },
            {
                "name": "Blue"
            }
        ],
        "keywords": [
            {
                "keywordName": "keywordName 1"
            },
            {
                "keywordName": "keywordName 2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "collectableId": 2,
        "itemCatalogNumber": 151,
        "itemName": "name 2...",
        "category": {
            "categoryType": "category Type..."
        },
        "itemDescription": "item desc 2...",
        "itemAge": 30,
        "condition": {
            "conditionName": "condition Name..."
        },
        "sold": 15,
        "colors": [
            {
                "name": "Green"
            },
            {
                "name": "White"
            },
            {
                "name": "Brown"
            }
        ],
        "keywords": [
            {
                "keywordName": "keywordName 1"
            },
            {
                "keywordName": "keywordName 2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

To open the modal with the selected data, i've added this code in the grid:

```
<a class="openModal" href="#updateModal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="' + item.itemCatalogNumber + '">' + item.itemCatalogNumber + '</a>
```

> Where:
>
> `data-id` contains the `itemCatalogNumber` number from the current selected item in the grid.

In this solution, I'm using the following:

1. **Array.prototype.filter()**.- To filter data given a value. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
2. jQuery 1.11.1.
3. Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.5.

```js
$(function() {
  var data = []; // Declare an array to store the json data from server.

  function loadCollectionIndex() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://dfjb.webcindario.com/getAllCollectables.php?action=all',
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: "json"
    }).then(function(items) {
      data = items; // Set the data variable with the current response from the server.
      var tbody = $('tbody');

      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        var colorString = '';
        var keywordString = '';

        item.colors.forEach(function(value, index, color) {
          if (index == (color.length - 1)) {
            colorString += value.name;
          } else {
            colorString += value.name + ', ';
          }
        });

        item.keywords.forEach(function(value, index, keyword) {
          if (index == (keyword.length - 1)) {
            keywordString += value.keywordName;
          } else {
            keywordString += value.keywordName + ', ';
          }
        });

        tbody.append('<tr id="itemCatalogNumberRow" class="newRow"><td class="itemCatalogNumber"><a class="openModal" href="#updateModal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="' + item.itemCatalogNumber + '">' + item.itemCatalogNumber + '</a></td><td class="itemName">' + item.itemName + '</td><td class="itemCategory">' + item.category.categoryType + '</td><td class="itemDescription">' + item.itemDescription + '</td><td class="itemAge">' + item.itemAge + '</td><td class="itemCondition">' + item.condition.conditionName + '</td><td class="itemColor">' + colorString + '</td><td class="itemKeyword">' + keywordString + '</td><td class="itemSold">' + item.sold + '</td></tr>');
      }
    });
  }
  loadCollectionIndex();


  // When the user clicks in the link, open the modal and show the current data.
  $(document).on("click", ".openModal", function() {
    var id = parseInt($(this).data("id"), 10); // Gets the data-id value (itemCatalogNumber).
    console.log(id);
    var result = {}; // Declare an object to store the current object to populate in the modal form.


    result = data.filter(function(x) {
      return x.itemCatalogNumber === id; // From the array, only return an object which matches with the criteria.
    })[0];
    console.log(result); // Show the object in the console.

    /*
      Set the values from the result object in every field in the form.
     */
    $("#updateCollectableSelect").append('<option value=' + result.collectableId + '>' + result.itemName + '</option>');
    $("#updateIdNum").text(result.collectableId);
    $("#updateItemCatalogNumber").val(result.itemCatalogNumber);
    $("#updateItemName").val(result.itemName);
    $("#updateItemAge").val(result.itemAge);
    $("#updateItemDescription").val(result.itemDescription);

    $("#addCatagorySelect").html('<option class="" value="select">Select Category</option>');
    $("#addCatagorySelect").append("<option value=" + result.category.categoryType + ">" + result.category.categoryType + "</option>");

    $("#addConditionSelect").html('<option class="" value="select">Select Condition</option>');
    $("#addConditionSelect").append("<option value=" + result.condition.conditionName + ">" + result.condition.conditionName + "</option>");

    $("#addColorSelect").html('<option class="" value="select">Select Color</option>');
    // Fills colors in the <select> tag.
    for (var i = 0; i < result.colors.length; i++) {
      $("#addColorSelect").append("<option value=" + result.colors[i].name + ">" + result.colors[i].name + "</option>");
    }

    $("#addKeywordSelect").html('<option class="" value="select">Select Keyword</option>');
    // Fills keywords in the <select> tag.
    for (i = 0; i < result.colors.length; i++) {
      $("#addKeywordSelect").append("<option value=" + result.keywords[i].keywordName + ">" + result.keywords[i].keywordName + "</option>");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <table border="1" class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Catalog Number</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Category Type</th>
          <th>Item Description</th>
          <th>Item Age</th>
          <th>Condition Name</th>
          <th>Colors</th>
          <th>Keywords</th>
          <th>Sold</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="updateModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"> Add an Item </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="updateItem">
              <form>
                <select name="dropDownMenu" id="updateCollectableSelect">
                  <option value="Select a Collectable">Select a Collectable</option>
                </select>
                <div>
                  <label>ID Number</label>
                  <br>
                  <span id="updateIdNum"></span>
                  <br>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                  <label>Catalog Number</label>
                  <input type="text" id="updateItemCatalogNumber">
                  <p class="error" id="updateItemCatalogNumberError"></p>
                  <br>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                  <label>Collectable Name</label>
                  <input type="text" id="updateItemName">
                  <p class="error" id="updateItemNameError"></p>
                  <br>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                  <label>Collectable Age</label>
                  <input type="text" id="updateItemAge">
                  <p class="error" id="updateItemAgeError"></p>

                  <br>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                  <label>Collectable Description</label>
                  <input type="text" id="updateItemDescription">
                  <p class="error" id="updateItemDescriptionError"></p>
                  <br>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="categorySelectDiv">
                  <select id="addCatagorySelect" class="" name="catagorySelect">
                    <option class="" value="select">Select Category</option>
                  </select>
                  <br>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="conditionSelectDiv">
                  <select id="addConditionSelect" class="" name="conditionSelect">
                    <option class="" value="select">Select Condition</option>
                  </select>
                  <br>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="addColorDiv">
                  <div id="colorSelectDiv">
                    <select id="addColorSelect" class="" name="colorSelect" multiple>
                      <option class="" value="select">Select Color</option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p>Hold down the Ctrl button to select multiple color options.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div id="addKeywordDiv">
                    <div id="keywordSelectDiv">
                      <select id="addKeywordSelect" class="" name="keywordSelect" multiple>
                        <option class="" value="select">Select Keyword</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <p>Hold down the Ctrl button to select multiple keyword options.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this help you.

Anyways, it would be helpful if you provide us your json data from your server, when you call to `getAllCollectables/all`.